# Helm values with build time env vars

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-deployment

I have a Helm chart and in the deployment, I want to provide some environment variable for my pods. During build time in my CI/CD setup, I have the values as env vars and I'm passing them now like this:

```
helm upgrade CHART_NAME helm --install --set-string webserver.env.DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL
```

I have like more then 20 env vars, can I access them somehow in my values.yml?

```
webserver:
  env:
    DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
```

Sadly this one doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helm does not resolve placeholders (environment variables) inside `values` files, but you can do it yourself in the CI/CD script, before passing the file to the `helm upgrade` command:

**values-env.yaml:**

```yaml
webserver:
  env:
    DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
```

**CI/CD script:**

```sh
eval "echo \"$(cat values-env.yaml)\"" >> values-ci.yaml
helm upgrade CHART_NAME helm --install --values values-ci.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

The better approach will be to create a values-override.yaml file and store all the values that needs to be set from Jenkins in the values-override file.
Use `sed` command to update the value-override.yaml to the jenkins env-variable. Use the override values.yaml in the Helm upgrade command.